# Is there a way to get notified when an IP address or website is online in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, ping

I am trying to host a website and want to get notified when that url comes online.

Comment: You need to provide more details as far as what you are trying to do, what software you are using to host the site, and how you expect to get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ping -i 60 -a <IP_ADDRESS>` sends an audible alarm when IP is online.

Comment: This sends an alarm if you can ping the webserver. This may the case before the site is online...

Comment: @dan1st Thanks, I will keep that it mind. It serves my purpose for now :)

Comment: @learner If this answer helped you, Mohit Singh would appreciate you accepting this answer, I think.